# How to resolve a 403 error inhibiting number of workers Google Cloud Dataflow can spin up?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-datasets

I know there are related questions, but I have been working on this for hours. I am trying to process and download a cleaned version of the Common Crawl dataset called C4, through tensorflow datasets using an Apache Beam pipeline with Google Cloud Dataflow to distribute the workload among several hundred workers. In keeping with the [instructions for generating big datasets with Apache Beam](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/beam_datasets), I followed the Google Cloud Dataflow [Quickstart instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python), setting up my project, billing, credentials, etc. all through the Google Cloud Console and then creating a virtual environment, installing tensorflow, and the google cloud sdk, then setting credentials with `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/json/from/Google-Cloud"`. When I then set MY_BUCKET, MY_PROJECT, and MY_REGION variables, and I actually run the instructions

```
pip install tfds-nightly[c4]
echo 'tfds-nightly[c4]' > /tmp/beam_requirements.txt
python -m tensorflow_datasets.scripts.download_and_prepare \
  --datasets=c4/en \
  --data_dir=gs://$MY_BUCKET/tensorflow_datasets \
  --beam_pipeline_options="project=$MY_PROJECT,job_name=c4,staging_location=gs://$MY_BUCKET/binaries,temp_location=gs://$MY_BUCKET/temp,runner=DataflowRunner,requirements_file=/tmp/beam_requirements.txt,experiments=shuffle_mode=service,region=$MY_REGION"
```

it begins to run, but I get a "Failed:Resize Instance Group Manager" message for a 403 error like every 20 seconds

[image]

and I'm limited to 2 workers when the console output keeps saying that it's trying to scale up to 1000.

```
.
.
.
I1014 15:43:05.446238 140556195309312 dataflow_runner.py:248] 2020-10-14T21:43:01.141Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
I1014 15:43:05.446516 140556195309312 dataflow_runner.py:248] 2020-10-14T21:43:01.171Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
I1014 15:49:42.444391 140556195309312 dataflow_runner.py:248] 2020-10-14T21:49:40.042Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 1 to 2.
I1014 15:49:47.653243 140556195309312 dataflow_runner.py:248] 2020-10-14T21:49:45.542Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 2 based on
the rate of progress in the currently running stage(s).
I1014 15:51:37.070624 140556195309312 dataflow_runner.py:248] 2020-10-14T21:51:36.931Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 2 to 1000.
I1014 16:39:49.413619 140556195309312 transport.py:179] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
I1014 16:39:49.448023 140556195309312 client.py:795] Refreshing access_token
I1014 17:39:53.158122 140556195309312 transport.py:179] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
I1014 17:39:53.191963 140556195309312 client.py:795] Refreshing access_token
I1014 18:39:54.347596 140556195309312 transport.py:179] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
I1014 18:39:54.377913 140556195309312 client.py:795] Refreshing access_token
I1014 19:39:59.015963 140556195309312 transport.py:179] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
I1014 19:39:59.051589 140556195309312 client.py:795] Refreshing access_token
.
.
.
```

I think this is a permissions issue, from the 403 error and related questions, but I followed the instructions in creating a service account and making it "Owner", so if I'm setting my credentials to the json file I got from the GC console, why would I lack permissions, how do I go about validating my credentials, etc. so as to stop getting these 403 errors and successfully spin up hundreds of workers?

Lastly, I thought this might be a quota issue, but in examining the quotas through Google Cloud Console, it seemed like the job wasn't bumping up against any quotas. Every one of them had a green checkmark and was well-short of full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES` refers to this [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#vm_instances), which isn't visible in the quotas page. To increase the quota, increase the CPU quota.

"If you need quota for more VM instances, request more CPUs because having more CPUs increases this quota."

You could also set [max_num_workers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options#python_11) to keep the number of VMs within your quota.

The 403 probably means the permission was denied because you didn't have enough quota, not because your SA didn't have any other permissions.

Comment: I don't understand, because in that first link you provide, it says "This quota is not visible in the Google Cloud Console, but it is set automatically by Compute Engine to be 10x your regular CPU quota", so even if my regular CPU quota were one, it would allow 10 VM instances, right? Even so, my region is "us-west1", where I have a quota of 24 CPUs, so why would I be running up against a limit for VM instances which is 10 times that size? As I said, only 2 workers get spun up, which is far beneath both quotas.

Comment: @crytting The issue is that Dataflow tried to spin up 1000 workers.The error spun up while "Resizing worker pool from 2 to 1000."

Comment: @crytting I don't know which machine you're using, but try adding --max_num_workers=4 or something small. If your CPU quota is only 24, then it doesn't really make sense to scale up to 1000 workers anyways, since it'll be using at least 1000 CPUs.

Comment: It does seem to have been a quota issue. When I requested a higher CPU quota (500) and set max_num_workers=450, it successfuly scaled up to 8 and then ran into another quota, and I'll just keep requesting quota increases as I hit them. Thanks for your help! Do you know off-hand how to check the status of quota increase requests? I'm getting some approved instantly and others are taking a long time, and I want to make sure they're still active.

Comment: @crytting Some quota increases are automatic. If yours needs an approval, then I believe you'll get a support ticket. Perhaps check the email or check the support page.